# How do I calculate a PCB antenna trace width?

Tags: rf, antenna, pcb-antenna, trace

I'm totally stuck here trying to find a single source that describes how to determine a PCB antenna trace width. I understand how to determine the length based on the targeted wavelength, but the width is lost on me.

To preface, I'm very new to this and am trying to design a half-wave curved dipole PCB trace antenna. The guide I'm using as a reference is from Texas Instruments. Click design guide at [this link](http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDC-ZLIGHT2-W).

In this TI DN041 guide it says the following in section **4 Designing a Half Wae Dipole Antenna on a PCB:**

> The width of the trace does have an impact on the antenna performance, particularly the bandwidth. In this design note we will stick to a width of  300  um (12 mils), and refer the reader to more thorough papers on antenna theory if they wish  to  probe  deeper  into  this  particular  property of  the  dipole.

So I went on a hunt to try to find these "thorough papers on antenna theory" and came up short. I did, however, find a [few](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/13422/trace-width-of-pcb-antenna) [resources](http://colinkarpfinger.com/blog/2010/the-dropouts-guide-to-antenna-design/) that pointed me to a broken link for an online "microstrip" calculator. I did some digging and found a new link to it [here](https://emclab.mst.edu/resources/tools/pcb-trace-impedance-calculator/) (click "Microstrip Trace").

Now I'm not sure that a PCB trace antenna counts as a microstrip trace because PCB trace antennas are not supposed to have anything on other layers above or below it so that the antenna performs well. Yet a microstrip has a groundplane underneath it as illustrated below:

[image]

Then I did some digging and found that this is used to calculate transmission lines and  that "[PCB antennas are not transmission line](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/6501/pcb-antenna-width)."

[Someone on this very site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/444843/1-4-wave-monopole-pcb-antenna-design) tried to use this calculator for that purpose and it was mentioned that their use of the microstrip calculator was incorrect due to the ground plane. So using a microstrip calculator seems to be incorrect (even though some people used it as such). So then how do I calculate it?

**So to summarize into a single question, how do I determine the width of a PCB trace antenna?**

Comment: Notice that at your last link ("someone on this very site"), there is no ground plane beneath the trace. Therefore this is not a microstrip structure. If you really want to optimize your antenna trace width I suspect you need to do a numerical analysis with an EM simulator like CST or HFSS.

Comment: And the answer to that question did include "you don't need a 50 ohm transmission line to make such an antenna in the first place. You don't want that ground underneath, because you want radiation of the monopole" so it's not true nobody mentioned it was incorrect.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, hence the reason why I reference it. People appear to be using the microstrip calculator for antenna traces, yet antenna traces have no ground plane below and microstrips do.

Comment: @ThePhoton I rephrased that line. I was more referencing how no one mentioned that their use of the microstrip calculator was incorrect for determineing the PCB trace width.

Comment: @Davbog fix your question as per what the photon says. That answer clearly states you should not use a micro strip calculator when trying to design an antenna.

Comment: @Andyaka fixed. I've looked at a lot of sources and had mixed it up in my memory. Thanks.

Comment: we're all here for the bounty tbh

Comment: TBH people make PhD thesis on how to design this type of devices... You should find a working design and copy it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

The TI reference design should include a layout. My advice is to copy that layout *exactly* for your first iteration and test it. Pay special attention to preserving the spacing between the antenna poles and the reference planes alongside (but not beneath!) them.

If it works well enough, go with it (it likely will.) If not, hope is not lost. You can adjust things a bit (spacing and width) to get things right, as the TI appnote said. To do this in a structured way you will need to acquire a antenna design tool and develop the skillset to run it, or talk to the FAE at the chip vendor.

Worst case? Hire a consultant. Which might be your best case if you've never done this before and you have bosses breathing down your neck for schedule.

Comment: I'll agree... people make PhD & master degree thesis about how to design an microstip antenna for a particular type of communication. I doubt that a neophyte could manage to build an antenna by himself in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.cypress.com/file/136236/download

Cypress has a great tutorial.

It will take some time to study it. Its a great one for begginers, but you will need something like a [minivna](https://www.google.com/search?q=minivna&client=ubuntu&hs=fRr&channel=fs&sxsrf=ALeKk02VgqHdYEs4Zle82v_TM900kpQOQw:1611606774057&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE5KOK97fuAhVSKBoKHWJDDMkQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=652) to get your hands on it. Theory is different from real life.

For example after designing an antenna for 2.4Ghz, my minivna shows me this when i use it to see which frequency is my antenna build for:
[image]

(The lower the graph, the better the signal)

You see as points 1 and 2, is where my antenna best functions. Around 2.4Ghz, but not exactly 2.4Ghz.

Also At point 3 it has a weaker signal.

My point is, it will take time to get there. Study as many sources as you can, gather information and keep testing.